# Firebase linker error XCode 8 beta 2

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to integrate Firebase in my iOS project without Cocoapods.I have followed all the instructions but I am getting a linker error on XCode8 beta2 as given below:

[image]

My framework dependencies look like following:

[image]

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the "Frameworks" Directory from the main project and every thing worked,
I think that those frameworks need to be recompiled after updating the XCODE or switching to swift 3 or choosing your team in the build settings[image]

Comment: Thanks, you made my day!

Comment: @user3636706 I'm happy to know that it helped some one, I lost a lot of precious time figuring this out